What is the APA7 rule when quoting a translated non-academic speech?
My field is in the humanities, and I need to quote a passage from an audio-visual recorded speech (around 30 words) in French, by a politician. It is for a paper written in English.
I would like to have the precise wording that they used rendered; in other words, I would like to quote it as a direct speech, not as an indirect speech (the precise wording being transcribed by a faithful translation). It seems to me this rationale makes totally sense, since a political speech is about a specific rhetoric, in contrary to scientific pieces.
It is difficult to find informations on this case:

https://www.scribbr.com/apa-examples/speech/

https://apastyle.apa.org/blog/cite-your-own-translations

https://research.wou.edu/c.php?g=1046948&p=7596966


The last link is quite straightforward:

Only quote an indirect source when absolutely necessary, for instance, when the original work is out of print or unavailable, or in a foreign language.

NB: With the APA restrictions, what I plan to do is to quote the passage in the original language, and accompanied (either in a note, or between brackets in the main text) with an English translation.
There is a related question here, but it concerned the quotation of a passage from an academic piece.

Although the related question concerned a quotation from an academic text, the APA guidance does not seem to assume this. Indeed, I would imagine that the rationale "Further, because it is not possible to codify how exact any given translation is, it would be inappropriate to put quotation marks around the translated words; again, your translation is a paraphrase." might be more relevant to speeches possibly using informal or idiomatic expressions. Anyway, your plan seems very reasonable.

I would object to a number of premises here. One, you can't have "the precise wording that they used rendered" when dealing with a translation. I also do not think that political speech is definitionally more precise. In fact, scientific writing is often criticized by being overly precised to the point it makes reading difficult.

For the purposes of citation, there is no difference between an "academic" and "non-academic" work.

@AzorAhai-him- Thank you. I changed to "specific (rhetoric)"

Now I'm not really sure what you mean at all.
